# Regex multiple exclusion and match for different patterns

Tags: regex

I want to exclude some specific words and if those words doesnt match, then should match an md5 hash for example.

Here a small log as example

```
"value": "ef51be4506d7d287abc8c26ea6c495f6", "u_jira_status": "", "u_quarter_closed": "", "file_hash": "ef51be4506d7d287abc8c26ea6c495f6", "escalation": "0", "upon_approval": "proceed", "correlation_id": "", "cyber_kill_change": "ef51be4506d7d287abc8c26ea6c495f6", "sys_id": "ef51be4506d7d287abc8c26ea6c495f6", "u_business_service": "", "destination_ip": "ef51be4506d7d287abc8c26ea6c495f6", u'test': u'9db92f08db4f951423c87d84f39619ef'
```

As you can see there is multiple values that should match, just excluding "value" and "id"

Here the regex I am using so far

```
([^value|^id](\":\s\"|':\su')\b)[a-fA-F\d]{32}\b
```

There is two cases where after the exclusion could be
"something": "hash"
'something': u'hash'

Whit the previous regex the result is the following.
[image: Test result]

The result is excluding value and id as expected, but there is a value called "cyber_kill_change" that is not matching for some reason and for the other ones is matching "file_hash", "destination_ip" and 'test' as expected.
Now as you can see in the previous image the matches are
h": "ef51be4506d7d287abc8c26ea6c495f6
p": "ef51be4506d7d287abc8c26ea6c495f6
t': u'9db92f08db4f951423c87d84f39619ef

Instead of just the MD5 (In this example is the same for the all 3 matches)
9db92f08db4f951423c87d84f39619ef

Can someone explain to me how to match correctly, please?

**Note**
For the exclusions I cannot use something similar to this
(?<!value|id)
The < and ! are not accepted by the software where I want to add the regex.
If it helps I am trying to use this regex for XSOAR, here some documentation of the permitted [Syntax](https://docs.paloaltonetworks.com/pan-os/9-1/pan-os-web-interface-help/objects/objects-custom-objects/objects-custom-objects-data-patterns/syntax-for-regular-expression-data-patterns)

Comment: So you can't use lookbehinds and can you use look*aheads*? If so, try something like [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y7kfqp/1). Your `[^value|^id]` is not doing what it looks you think. This is a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) matching any character not in the list, equivalent to e.g. `[^adeiluv|^]`.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I cannot use any lookaheads or lookbehinds, where I want to use the regex does not permit !, < or =

Comment: Can you use [capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)? An idea to [match what you don't want but capture what you need](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick). See [this other demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y7kfqp/3) (where `id` or `value` occures would result in empty captures for the *first group*).

Comment: I'm just limited to use the following
https://docs.paloaltonetworks.com/pan-os/9-1/pan-os-web-interface-help/objects/objects-custom-objects/objects-custom-objects-data-patterns/syntax-for-regular-expression-data-patterns
I tried something similar to you demo, but is matching "value", "*id" and also matches the characters before the MD5, what I'm looking for is just match the MD5 value, for example just the 
9db92f08db4f951423c87d84f39619ef

Answer (score 0):

"cyber_kill_change" ends with the character 'e' which is the same as the last character in "value", which is why it was also excluded. The problem started when you use the brackets `[]`, which is a "character class", which means "any character in the word value or Id will be match as a single character, not as a word". It is the same as:

```
[value|id]=(v|a|l|u|e|i|d)
```

To match the exact word, you can use `(value|id)` you may try this Expression:

```
((?<!(value|id))(\":\s\"|':\su')\b)[a-fA-F\d]{32}\b
```

I used [CyrilEx Regex Tester](https://extendsclass.com/regex-tester.html) to check the expression and I got the same result as shown in the following image:

[Regex Tester](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIhO5.jpg)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, unfortunately I'm limited in some aspects and cannot use "<" or "!", this is a great solution but not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately, every possible way without brackets has been tested with no luck. as mentioned before, brackets are used for "character class", which means using the word will divide the word character by character, which will reflect in the result as you show in your question.